# Artifacts on cube after modulo on coordinates

Tags: node-editor, artifacts, texture-coordinates

[image: Cube with artifacts]

This happens with the following node configuration:

[image: Modulo node configuration]

It is caused by the modulo (or Fract) operation. I stumbled upon this problem while trying to repeat coordinates on a cube. It works fine on a plane.

Any idea why is this happening? The effect is similiar to z-fighting and only happens in perspective view. In orthographic that side is black. Is the modulo operation for some reason unable to determine a value at that side of the cube ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Modulo* node, when used with vector input repeats the output values at regular intervals, in this case $1$ unit.

You are using *Generated* texture coordinates as input which uses the objects size for coordinates, meaning it that maximum X,Y or Z are always considered at coordinate $1$ regardless off absolute dimensions.

Since in this case geometry is a cube, there is a planar face at precisely the coordinate X=$1$ which is the boundary point exactly where the Modulo pattern repeats itself and goes from black to white.

And that is what you are seeing, it is not Z-Fighting per-se but it is exactly the same kind of mathematical imprecision computers can't really solve well.

[image]

Comment: For the math minded, [Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the remainder of input after division by value. In this case  value is 1.0.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the correction, math is really not my forte. Answer corrected